# Automatically log-in on page load

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

Basically I have the following website which allows account customers to login to the website by filling in the appropriate details:[here](http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_golden/login.php)

I have created a seperate login page which is identical with the login values already filled in: [here](http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_golden/login-guest.php)

and I have basically added in the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn-login').click();
});
```

This is so it automatically logs in as a guest when you go to the second link. Although it works okay, when you logout as a guest and try to log back in via the second link it redirects to the first link (login.php) and I can't understand why since all the second link is doing is submitting the correct values.

Is there a better way of doing this or is there a way of preventing this from happening?

If I remove the redirect, if you logout then try to go to the automatic login link, it takes you to the page and has all the details filled in but it doesn't log you in automatically.

Any help would be much appreciated.

See below code for the login (session-controller.php)

```
<?php

require_once("controllers/server.filter.php");
require_once('models/server.php');
require_once("models/useraccount.php");
require_once("models/sql.php");

class SessionController {

private static $login_status;
private static $redirect_url;
public static $form_action;

## Getters ##

private static function get_loginstatus() {return self::$login_status;}

## Setters ##

private static function set_loginstatus($in_str) {self::$login_status = $in_str;}

## Functions ##

public static function validate_user() {

    UserAccount::set_username($_REQUEST['txt-username']);  
    UserAccount::set_password($_REQUEST['txt-password']);  

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        // Does user exist?
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM tblusers WHERE UserName = :in_username";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $param = Filter::san_str_html(UserAccount::get_username());

        $stmt->bindParam(':in_username', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);   

        $stmt->execute();

        $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 

        $stmt->closeCursor();



        if ($number_of_rows <= 0) {

            self::set_loginstatus("The user does not exist in our database, please try again.");
            $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();
            self::redirect(false);

        } else {

            // User verified, check password...
            self::verify_password();

        }

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage());
    }

    $pdo = null;

}

private static function verify_password() {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        // Does the password given match the password held?
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblusers WHERE UserName = :in_username AND Password = :in_password";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $param1 = UserAccount::get_password();
        $param2 = Filter::san_str_html(UserAccount::get_username());

        $stmt->bindParam(':in_username', $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':in_password', $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);      

        $stmt->execute();

        $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage());
    }

    $pdo = null;

    if ($number_of_rows == 1) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = UserAccount::get_username();

        // Begin verification.. 
        self::set_useraccount(true);

    } else {

        self::set_loginstatus("Verification failed! Password incorrect, please try again.");
        $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();
        self::redirect(false);

    }

}

private static function verify_account() { 

    // Account types: 9 = Disabled, 0 = Normal/Restricted, 1 = Administrative
    if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 9) {
        self::set_loginstatus("Verification failed! This account has been disabled."); ## Account disabled
        $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();
        self::redirect(false);

    } else 

        // User login types: 9 = Disabled, 0 = Normal/Restricted, 1 = Administrative
        if (UserAccount::get_usertype() == 9) {
            self::set_loginstatus("Verification failed! This login has been disabled."); ## User login disabled
            $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();
            self::redirect(false);

        } else {

            // Set redirect url here
            if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1) {
                self::$redirect_url = 'controlpanel.php';
            }

            if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 0 && UserAccount::get_usertype() == 1) {
                self::$redirect_url = 'controlpanel.php';
            }

            if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 0 && UserAccount::get_usertype() == 0) {
                self::$redirect_url = 'newbooking.php';
            }

            // All ok, set user and account properties
            return true;

        }

}

public static function set_useraccount($redirect_bool) {

    // If username session is set...
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

        UserAccount::set_username($_SESSION['username']);

        // Query Database for the rest of the data
        $pdo = new SQL();
        $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

        try {

            $query = "SELECT AccountName 
                      FROM tblusers 
                      WHERE UserName = :in_username";

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $param1 = UserAccount::get_username();

            $stmt->bindParam(':in_username', $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            // Parse
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

            $stmt->closeCursor();

        }

        catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage());
        }   

        UserAccount::set_accountname($row['AccountName']);

        try {

            $query = "SELECT a.Id, a.AccountName, a.AccountNumber, a.AccountEmail, a.AccountTel, 
                             a.AccountContact, a.AccountType, a.PaymentType, u.UserName, 
                             u.FullName, u.UserEmail, u.UserTel, u.UserType
                      FROM tblaccounts a JOIN tblusers u 
                      ON a.AccountName = u.AccountName
                      WHERE a.AccountName = :in_accname
                      AND u.UserName = :in_username";

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $param2 = UserAccount::get_accountname();
            $param3 = UserAccount::get_username();

            $stmt->bindParam(':in_accname', $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':in_username', $param3, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            // Parse
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

        }

        catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage());
        }   

        // Set properties and sessions variables
        UserAccount::set_id($row['Id']);
        UserAccount::set_accountname($row['AccountName']);
        UserAccount::set_accountnumber($row['AccountNumber']);
        UserAccount::set_accountemail($row['AccountEmail']);
        UserAccount::set_fullname($row['FullName']);
        UserAccount::set_accounttel($row['AccountTel']);
        UserAccount::set_accountcontact($row['AccountContact']);
        UserAccount::set_accounttype((int)$row['AccountType']);
        UserAccount::set_paymenttype((int)$row['PaymentType']);
        UserAccount::set_useremail($row['UserEmail']);
        UserAccount::set_usertel($row['UserTel']);
        UserAccount::set_usertype((int)$row['UserType']);

        if (self::verify_account()) {

            switch (UserAccount::get_paymenttype()) {
                case 0:
                $_SESSION['ua-paymenttype-asstr'] = 'Credit/Debit Card';
                self::$form_action = 'addressdetails.php';
                break;
                case 1:
                $_SESSION['ua-paymenttype-asstr'] = 'Account';
                self::$form_action = 'makebooking.php';
                break;
                case 2:
                $_SESSION['ua-paymenttype-asstr'] = 'Cash';
                self::$form_action = 'makebooking.php';
                break;
            }

            switch (UserAccount::get_usertype()) {
                case 9:
                $_SESSION['ua-usertype-asstr'] = 'Disabled/Suspended';
                break;
                case 0:
                $_SESSION['ua-usertype-asstr'] = 'Standard';
                break;
                case 1:
                $_SESSION['ua-usertype-asstr'] = 'Account Administrator';
                break;
            }

            switch (UserAccount::get_accounttype()) {
                case 9:
                $_SESSION['ua-accounttype-asstr'] = 'Disabled/Suspended';
                break;
                case 0:
                $_SESSION['ua-accounttype-asstr'] = '  ';
                break;
                case 1:
                $_SESSION['ua-accounttype-asstr'] = '(SA)';
                break;
            }

            // Redirect
            if ($redirect_bool) {
                self::redirect(true);
            }

        }

    } else {

        self::set_loginstatus("Pre-requisite failure! Browser not supporting cookies!");
        $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();

        self::redirect(false);

    }

}

private static function redirect($auth_bool) {

    //parent::set_sessionstate(true); ## Set session to active -- persistance to DB

    //self::$determine_session_type(); ## Set session type --  persistance to DB

    if ($auth_bool == true) {

        $doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        self::set_loginstatus('');
        $_SESSION['login-status'] = self::get_loginstatus();

        header("Location: ".self::$redirect_url);

    } else {

        header("Location: login.php");

    }

}


}

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What are you trying to achieve? What do you have and what do you want to get?

Comment: Basically, when you go to http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_golden/login-guest.php it should login automatically, for this page I have filled in the text boxes on the login page and using jquery I have made it so the submit button is pressed as soon as the page is loaded. For some reason when you log out though and try to go to that same link, it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying things and have login-guest.php simply set the appropriate session variables and redirect them inside, thus removing the login script from the mix altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since you're not showing the actual login/logout code, but maybe you're not destroying the session correctly?

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

EDIT: Nevermind, I think I may have misread your problem.